# HashMap implementation in Python

Tags: python, hash-map

Here's my implementation of a bare-bones HashMap in Python.
Expected behavior, it returns None if a key is missing,
When a key is inserted the second time it just overwrites the first value.

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = [None for _ in range(16)]
        self.size = 0

    def get(self, key):
        key_hash = self._hash(key)
        index = self._position(key_hash)
        if not self.store[index]:
            return None
        else:
            list_at_index = self.store[index]
            for i in list_at_index:
                if i.key == key:
                    return i.value
            return None

    def put(self, key, value):
        p = Node(key, value)
        key_hash = self._hash(key)
        index = self._position(key_hash)
        if not self.store[index]:
            self.store[index] = [p]
            self.size += 1
        else:
            list_at_index = self.store[index]
            if p not in list_at_index:
                list_at_index.append(p)
                self.size += 1
            else:
                for i in list_at_index:
                    if i == p:
                        i.value = value
                        break

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def _hash(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return key
        result = 5381
        for char in key:
            result = 33 * result + ord(char)
        return result

    def _position(self, key_hash):
        return key_hash % 15


class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hashmap = HashMap()
    hashmap.put(2, 12)
    hashmap.put('asd', 13)
    hashmap.put(2, 11)
    print(hashmap.get(2))
    print(hashmap.get('asd'))
    print(hashmap.get('ade'))
```

Invite comments and reviews.

Comment: I'd consider some hash functions described here: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed for really good comparision of fast hashing algorithms

Comment: Why this hardcoded 15 in _position?

Answer (score 9):

- Initialization of `store` as a list of `None` does not really buy you anything in terms of efficiency, but complicates the code quite a bit. I recommend to initialize it with empty lists instead.
- `put` iterates the list twice. A single pass is sufficient:

  ```
      for i in list_at_index:
          if i == p:
              i.value = p.value
              return
      list_at_index.append(p)
      self.size += 1
  ```
- `store` has 16 slots, but `key_hash % 15` returns only 15 possible values. The last slot is never used.
- Absence of `delete` is somewhat questionable.

Answer (score 6):

You can also collapse the loop in the `get()` method using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) replacing:

```
for i in list_at_index:
    if i.key == key:
        return i.value
return None
```

with:

```
return next((i.value for i in self.store[index] if i.key == key), None)
```

As a side note, I think it would be a good idea to avoid hardcoding the numbers like  `5381` or `15` in the code and make them proper constants or hashmap initialization parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of rolling your own hash function `_hash` you should use Python’s built-in [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: I think he/she knows, because of the '-' before hash, but challenged herself to create the whole thing

Answer (score 3):

You can define `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` instead of `get` and `put` to use square bracket notation (I don't think you would have to change the functions at all, just the names).